# Minimum version of ECMAScript required for kriskowal's Q promise library

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, q

What minimum version of ECMAScript is required by kriskowal's Q promise library?

I am aware of the compat. table: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ but this just specifies ES6 is required to run Promise natively i.e. excluding third-party Promise libraries.

The reason I'm asking is because I want to be sure it works on Android 4.0 (and up) webviews. As far as I can tell from looking at the compat table the Android 4.0 webview only supports a subset of ES5.

It seems Q might support engines running sub 5 [see Q change log 0.1.7](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/7e4c79a5715b3981b2d4339381a0a3faa01f3b21/CHANGES.md#017)

Comment: I'm guessing ES 5.1, the real question is; why would it matter ?

Comment: https://github.com/kriskowal/q; I'm not sure that there is one specified. I wouldn't plan on using it in IE6 though.

Comment: It's tested in Travis using Node 0.10. That and the compat table should give you a rough idea of what's supported.

Comment: You need to worry about the minimum version of the engine required by the module not the ES version [Q package.json](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/package.json#L42)

Comment: It appears the [Q works even with ES3](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/7e4c79a5715b3981b2d4339381a0a3faa01f3b21/CHANGES.md#017)

Comment: @jaime I do not agree. Q itself will require an ECMAScript feature-set and I want to determine what the minimum ECMAScript version required is to satisfy the set.

Comment: @Bergi thank you. Want change log version are you referring to deduce that it works on ES3.

Comment: @adeneo that is not the real question but anyway I have modified my question to include the reason I am asking but the reason is not required to answer the question.

Comment: Why did my question get a down-vote? If you going to downvote please include a comment why and I will review the question. As far as I can tell this is a valid question.

Comment: @StevenMarkFord - Q generally works in every major browser or other place you could use it, because just about "everything" has been using at least ES 5.1 for almost ten years. In ES6 promises are already supported, so that's not an issue. If Q works in ES3 as well, it would work in ever version of EcmaScript since 1999, so again, the real question is why would it matter, are you planning on developing for Netscape Navigator or other twenty year old browsers ?

Comment: @adeneo Actually Android 4.0 which was released 5 years ago (not 10) only supports a subset of ES 5.0 so question does matter.

Comment: @StevenMarkFord 0.1.7 "*shimmed ES5 Object.create in addition to Object.freeze for compatibility on non-ES5 engines*"

Comment: @Bergi I think your answer is sufficient, thanks! If you create an answer with that I will accept it.